# What spacecraft part is Mike Pence touching in this photo?

Tags: identify-this-object

In this photograph, Vice President Mike Pence is touching an item labelled "Critical Space Flight Hardware".  What is it?  Has the photo been doctored?

[image]

Comment: related but different: [Satellite manufacture and cleanliness](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23792/12102)

Comment: @uhoh: Thanks.  Interestingly, his name never appears in that question or its answers, so it did not show up in my search for previous questions.

Comment: yes it's not really related, but it's one of those images/scenarios/memes that is impossible to forget!

Comment: Is there anyone here, who upon reading the title alone, did not immediately know which picture this question was referring to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The photo is legit, according to [Time](http://time.com/4848951/mike-pence-nasa-do-not-touch/), [Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/post-politics/wp/2017/07/07/internet-explodes-after-pence-touches-flight-hardware-labeled-do-not-touch/?utm_term=.4e22ad7ade9d), [NBC News](https://www.nbcnews.com/news/us-news/photo-captures-mike-pence-ignores-nasa-s-do-not-touch-n780576), [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2017/jul/08/mike-pence-touches-nasa-equipment-right-next-to-do-not-touch-sign), etc.

The coverage by the Washington Post says:

> During a visit to NASA’s Kennedy Space Center in Florida on Thursday,
>   Vice President Pence solemnly reached out and touched **the Orion
>   spacecraft's titanium forward bay cover**, placing his full palm just
>   below a sign that read: “Critical Space Flight Hardware 'DO NOT
>   TOUCH.' "

[The manufacturer has an article](https://www.lockheedmartin.com/en-us/news/features/2017/orion-parachute-protection.html) which discusses the forward bay cover in some detail.

> Parachutes aren’t built to withstand the 5,000-degree temperatures
>   upon re-entry – they would be too heavy and unable to generate enough
>   drag to slow the spacecraft down – so the forward bay cover protects
>   them until just the right moment.

Comment: it looks doctored, anything that's not to be touched wouldn't have a sign taped on it with sticky tape, which leaves hard to remove residue when the tape itself is removed. And your sources aren't exactly trustworthy...

Comment: @jwenting second one is doctored, but it seems that it is generally agreed that the first one is real. https://twitter.com/VP/status/883408914196332544 WaPo is pretty trustworthy, and for something like this they can be expected to have done their homework. It happened.